# How to cancel, undo Entity Framework changed?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I had bind an Entity object to my UI (`WPF`), a Edit People window, when I changed any camp and click button Save, it will save it in my DB, close the window and update listPeople (`DataGrid`), in my Save button has just fallow code (db is my `DbContext` )

```
    private void Inserir_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            db.Peoples.Add(people);
            db.SaveChanges();
            MessageBox.Show("Register saved");
            this.Close();
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

This is working, but I have a problem, when I changed any camp and click Close button, it will not save in DB, but my change is updated to listPeople
I need when clicked Close button, my DbContext reset all values to original values (If edited, added or removed, undo it)

Event of Close button

```
    private void btClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
```

Event of PeopleEdit.Closed

```
    private void listPeople_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (listPeople.SelectedItem == null)
            return;

        Dados.People p = listPeople.SelectedItem as Dados.People;
        EditPeopleep = new EditPeople(p);
        ep.Closed += (s, arg) => { listPeople.ItemsSource = db.Peoples.ToList(); };
        ep.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not edit the Person in the dialog. Get a copy and edit that.

If the user clicks OK, THEN save the changes.

```
var p = listPeople.SelectedItem as Dados.People;
var vm = new PersonViewModel{Name = p.Name, Tel=p.Tel};
var ep = new EditPeople(vm);
if(ep.ShowDialog()){
    p.Name = vm.Name;
    p.Tel = vm.Tel;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

For the Create Person,

```
var vm = new PersonViewModel{Name = "name", Tel="tel"};
var ep = new EditPeople(vm);
if(ep.ShowDialog()){
    var p = new Dados.People();
    p.Name = vm.Name;
    p.Tel = vm.Tel;
    db.Peoples.Add(p);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

It is possible to have a system for Undo-Redo but that is very complicated.

You should make PersonViewModel implement INotifyPropertyChanged, then you can bind to it in the dialog.

```
public class PersonViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name{ get{return _name;}
                        set{ SetProperty(ref _name, value);}}
    private string _tel;
    public string Tel{ get{return _tel;}
                        set{ SetProperty(ref _tel, value);}}

    public PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void SetProperty<T>(ref T field, T value, 
         [CallerMemberName] string name = ""){
         field = value;
         if(PropertyChanged != null)
             PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));


    }



}
```

If you have many properties in your ViewModel, use Automapper to copy them.

Comment: Great! I had not thought this idea, this is a solution, but if I take this solution, all Binding in the dialog will not function for me, because I had make Binding for facilitate the process of pass values. But this is good idea

Comment: You can bind to the PersonViewModel, if you make it implement INotifyPropertyChanged.